# Adding a "where" clause produces a timeout

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to perform a select query in my schema, but when I add a "where" clause the performance drops and I end up with a timeout error.

The following query is apparently working (despite being slow)

```
select
    count(*),
    avg(ifac),max(ifac),min(ifac),std(ifac),
    year(pubmed_article.publication) as pubYear
from test.pubmedjournal,test.pubmed_article,test.impactfactor
where (pubmed_article.title like '%parameter%' or pubmed_article.abstract like '%parameter%') 
    and pubmed_article.pubmedjournal_idpubmedjournal = pubmedjournal.idpubmedjournal 
    and impactfactor.pubmedjournal_idpubmedjournal=pubmedjournal.idpubmedjournal
    and impactfactor.date = year(pubmed_article.publication)
group by pubYear;
```

Nevertheless, if I add an additional where clause **and impactfactor.ifac >1.0**, the query stops working

```
select
    count(*),
    avg(ifac),max(ifac),min(ifac),std(ifac),
    year(pubmed_article.publication) as pubYear
from test.pubmedjournal,test.pubmed_article,test.impactfactor
where (pubmed_article.title like '%parameter%' or pubmed_article.abstract like '%parameter%') 
    and pubmed_article.pubmedjournal_idpubmedjournal = pubmedjournal.idpubmedjournal 
    and impactfactor.pubmedjournal_idpubmedjournal=pubmedjournal.idpubmedjournal
    and impactfactor.date = year(pubmed_article.publication)
    and impactfactor.ifac >1.0
group by pubYear;
```

After searching a little bit in stackoverflow I've seen that probably I could address that problem using indexes, but I am not sure about that. Any clue about why this is not working?

Those are my table structures (in case they are helpful):

```
+-------------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                         | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idpubmed_article              | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title                         | varchar(1000)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| abstract                      | varchar(20000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| publication                   | date           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pubmedjournal_idpubmedjournal | int(11)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE test.pubmedjournal;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idpubmedjournal   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title             | varchar(400) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| abbreviated_title | varchar(400) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE test.impactfactor;
+-------------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idimpactfactor                | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date                          | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ifac                          | decimal(10,2) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pubmedjournal_idpubmedjournal | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Yes, indexes will help but it's hard to give you a specific answer. Building proper indexes is a process involving studying your whole project requirements. It's very broad. As a very quick-fix solution, just add a **multi-column index** in some of the columns of your `WHERE` clause including that `impactfactor.ifac` column. Beware: **order of columns on the index is critical** you need to decide on that. Also If you have lots of `INSERT`s in your application this may bite you.

Comment: Adding the multi-column indexes has solved the problem. I need to review the indexes because I'm not sure I've done it in the propper way, but apparently it is working (it takes about 7-9s whilst before it was 30ish). Thanks for your feedback.